# Replace commas with pipes, but not the commas enclosed in double quotes

Tags: perl, csv

I have a record set that looks like this

```
"BOSW0001","Mr","Wayne","Boswell","Wayne,Jessica & Lyn","31 Baker St"
"ELLI0007","Mrs","Bronwyn","Elliott","Bronwyn, Paul & Arianne","98A Dandaraga Rd"
"KENN0001","Mr","Leigh","Kenning","Leigh & Beth,Cole","22 Lake St"
```

I want to replace the comma (`,`) with pipe (`|`) without replacing the comma inside of

```
"Leigh & Bethie,Coles"
"Waynez,Jessy & Lyne"
"Bronwynie, Paula & Arianne"
```

How can I do this using regular expression or other methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't do it with a regular expression; you do it with a proper CSV parser. Here's an (untested) example using [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/module/HMBRAND/Text-CSV_XS-1.01/CSV_XS.pm) - the best in the biz.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $in_file = "whatever.csv";
my $out_file = "new.dat";

open my $fh, '<', $in_file or die "$in_file: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $out_file or die "$out_file: $!";

my $in_csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;
my $out_csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { sep_char => '|', eol => "\n" } );

while( my $row = $in_csv->getline( $fh ) ) { 
    $out_csv->print( $out_fh, $row );
}
```

Comment: There are actually 3 bugs in your untested example: 1. `readline` should be `getline`; 2. the options to `new` should be in a hashref i.e. `new( { sep_char => '|' } )`; 3. you might need to specify `eol` option (default it's `$\ ` and `$\ ` is by default undef) to prevent all the rows from being printed in a single line. Maybe you can use `new( { sep_char => '|', eol => $/ } )`.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of TIMTOWTDI, here is an example using the core module [Text::ParseWords](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aParseWords).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords 'parse_line';

foreach my $line (<DATA>) {
  print join '|', parse_line(',', 1, $line);
}

__DATA__
"BOSW0001","Mr","Wayne","Boswell","Wayne,Jessica & Lyn","31 Baker St"
"ELLI0007","Mrs","Bronwyn","Elliott","Bronwyn, Paul & Arianne","98A Dandaraga Rd"
"KENN0001","Mr","Leigh","Kenning","Leigh & Beth,Cole","22 Lake St"
```

Comment: I don't know why so many people reach for Text::CSV when this core module usually does the job just as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about utilizing the context in which the comma appears (between double-quotes):

```
s/","/"|"/g
```

Comment: What if a record contains an escaped quote followed by a comma?

Comment: No problem.  It wasn't so popular (I was downvoted almost as much as up), because there are several unlikely cases where it will break.  But often you know certain things about your data and the quick, easy solution is good enough.  Better, in fact, than spending lots of time on a more complex solution that might not be necessary.

Comment: @paddy, Indeed, your solution is I think more practical and very easy to apply without thinking too much for a complex answer.

Thanks again man cheers!

Comment: Quote of the day 
"quick and  easy solution is good enough. Better, in fact, than spending lots of time on a more complex solution that might not be necessary."

Paddy

Comment: Hahaha, glad you appreciated.  But before I endorse a habit of slackery, just beware...  because it takes a fair bit of discretion to determine that a solution with known flaws will be okay.  This approach is *not* okay for industrial code unless you are in *complete* control of the data.  I've done a lot of work on live television where I've had less than 30 seconds to fix a bug, recompile and deploy.  And you get used to doing whatever is necessary to fix it *quick*!  You can fix it *properly* after broadcast. =)

Comment: hahaha I'm actually new in Perl and it is what we used for pre-processing record data at work with a very short turn-around time for every job, that's why I resorted to your solution and I didn't get production issue :) –