# Replacing Quote-and-Multiple-Comma Delimiters in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I have a very large file that I need to parse with Perl.  The file format (which I cannot change) was originally written to allow the file to open in Excel as a CSV.  Specifically to this problem, I need to replace the delimiter in each line with a pipe (|).  Normally this is not a hard job, but I have a few issues (below) and while I do have a solution I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish my task.

1. The data itself contains comments with commas (meaning I cannot find and replace on comma)
2. Each "cell" worth of data is encapsulated in quotation marks, but if a cell was blank then no quotation marks are present

Example Line in file:

```
"Foo Bar","More Foo","More Bar",,,,,"Yet More","Comma,Separated,Statement"
```

My current solution looks something like the code below.  It works, but it seems inelegant and requires processing every line multiple times (something I want to avoid as this file is very large).

```
# Change the delimiter
$line =~ s/",,,,,"/|||||/g;
$line =~ s/",,,,"/||||/g;
$line =~ s/",,,"/|||/g;
$line =~ s/",,"/||/g;
$line =~ s/","/|/g;

$line =~ s/^"//;     # Remove leading quotation mark
$line =~ s/"$//;     # Remove trailing quotation mark
```

Can anyone out there help me find a faster and more elegant solution?

Comment: I can accept this as a duplicate.  For some reason I had not considered the problem in the way outlined in that thread to find it.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Text::CSV_XS](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_XS). Read each line, get each of the values, and rejoin with a pipe. Let the module handle all the formatting issues for you.

See the code in [friedo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309376/2766176) to [Replace commas with pipes, but not the commas enclosed in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17309314/2766176).